# Solr highlighting : extract complete sentence

Tags: solr, highlighting

As I'm saying in title, i want to get a complete sentence when i search with highlighting.

Actually, i get a result which is cut in middle of a word.

For example, if I'm searching for the word "complete", I get `ying in title, i want to get a complete sentence wh` but I want the complete sentence `As I'm saying in title, i want to get a complete sentence when i search with highlighting`.

I've already tried to use "fragmenter" but I haven't any result.

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks and sorry for my english.

Comment: could you please give an example what is the current behavior an what is your goal?!

Comment: When i use highlighting, I get a sentence cut in middle of a word. If I'm shearching for example "complete", I get "ying in title, i want to get a complete sentence wh" but I want the complete sentence "As I'm saying in title, i want to get a complete sentence when i search with highlighting".

Comment: Or if i can't have a complete sentence, i would like the words be not cut.

Answer (score 1):

Also check if your request handler or query parameter has hl.useFastVectorHighlighter set to true. If the field that it generates summaries on are not set up with the correct term settings as mentioned in the wiki, the words could cut as you describe.

Comment: We had the same problems with `FastVectorHighlighter`: it often truncated the word at the beginning. I suspect the `org.apache.lucene.search.vectorhighlight.SimpleFragListBuilder` to be the root of the problem, it seems to add a margin of 6 character to the beginning of the fragment. Anyway, you can provide your own implementation of `FragListBuilder` with `margin = 0` to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you find your answer here: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters

Take a look at the parameter hl.snippets and hl.fragsize, wehere you can define the length of the returned fragment - so you could set the value to the fieldsize (if the field isn't so large).

An other interesting parameter in your case is [hl.fragmenter](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters#hl.fragmenter)

Comment: I know this parameters but words are cut... I can't use the complete field because many documents like pdf, doc are indexed.

Comment: But i don't know the hl.fragmenter parameter. Have you some examples ?

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364301/solr-using-regex-fragmenter-to-extract-paragraphs

Comment: When i use some regex, i get no sentence. I already tested regex but i can't have results i would like.

Comment: The regex must match the result which I want ? For example a sentence ? Because I tried regex sentence and it didn't work. Like "[A-Z].*[\.\?!]" for example....

Answer (score 0):

got almost the same problem cutting words. As I just mentioned over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13362966/1818062) you could use another BoundaryScanner. 
This gave me perfect results.